# evaluating the required input from a html field which holds 0 as value?

Tags: php

I have some of radio buttons and checkboxes elements in my HTML form which holds 0 as value. typically i would check for the required values using two functions `isset()` or `!empty()` while `isset()` works quite well without hindrance but this is not the case with `empty()` as logically 0 represents boolean and hence `empty(0)` returns true. which is kind of bug when you evaluates integer 0 using `empty()`. i would like to know the workaround so that it evaluates integer `empty(0)` as false. one solution i could think of was using `strlen($variable) >= 1` , is there any better way or it is fine using `strlen()`?

thank you

Comment: Joseph's solution is the best. Anything coming out of _GET or _POST is a string, so simply do a strict compare against an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if a variable is exactly a value with three equals: `===`

```
if( $variable === 0 ) {
```

will only be true if the variable is actually 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use triple equal   `$variable===0`